# If a function is extended to make it periodic then must the integration limits also be extended?

Tags: integration, trigonometry, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, trigonometric-integrals

The following extract is taken from ["Riley, Hobson and Bence - Mathematical methods for physics and engineering", Section 12.5 - "Non-periodic functions", page 422 and 423](https://www.sicyon.com/resources/library/pdf/Math4phys.pdf):

> Find the Fourier series of $f(x)=x^2\,$ for $\,\,0\lt x \le 2$

---

> We must first make the function periodic. We do this by extending the range of interest to $−2 \lt x \le 2$ in such a way that $f(x)=f(-x)$ and then letting $f(x+4k) = f(x)$, where $k$ is any integer. This is shown in ﬁgure 12.5.

[image: Graph of f(x) with extended range]

> Now we have an even function of period 4. The Fourier series will faithfully represent $f(x)$ in the range, $−2 \lt x \le 2$, although not outside it. Firstly we note that since we have made the specified function even in $x$ by extending the range, all the coeﬃcients $b_n$ will be zero.

Where $$b_n=\frac{2}{L}\int_{x_0}^{x_0+L}f(x)\sin\left(\frac{2\pi nx}{L}\right)dx\tag{12.5}$$
similarly $$a_n=\frac{2}{L}\int_{x_0}^{x_0+L}f(x)\cos\left(\frac{2\pi nx}{L}\right)dx\tag{12.6}$$ where $x_0$ is arbitrary but is often taken as $0$ or $-\frac{L}{2}$ and $L$ is the period of $f(x)$.

> Now we apply $(12.5)$ and $(12.6)$ with $L = 4$ to determine the remaining coefficients: $$a_n=\frac{2}{4}\int_{-2}^{2}x^2\cos\left(\frac{2\pi nx}{4}\right)dx=\frac{4}{4}\int_{0}^{2}x^2\cos\left(\frac{\pi nx}{2}\right)dx$$

The textbook then goes on the evaluate the Fourier series for $x^2$ on $]0,2]$  (which I won't go through here as that is not what this question is about).

---

The following related question I asked on "Chegg Study" website is [here](https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/fourier-series-f-x-cos-5-x-given-f-r-~-2-4-1-1-cos-nz-q32702042):

> Show that the Fourier series of $f(x)=\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$ for $-\pi\lt x \lt \pi$ is given by 
>   $$f(x)=\frac{2}{\pi}+\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}\cos(nx)}{4n^2 - 1}$$

---

So my attempt at the finding the Fourier series for $\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$ on the interval $-\pi \lt x \lt \pi$ is by using the same method for the previous case $f(x) = x^2$ above.

Since $\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$ is **not** periodic on $-\pi \lt x \lt \pi$,$\,$ I will extend the interval to $-2\pi \lt x \lt 2\pi$

A plot of the extended function is shown below:

[image: cos(x/2)]]

Then by $(12.6)$,
$$\begin{align}a_n &=\frac{2}{L}\int_{x_0}^{x_0+L}f(x)\cos\left(\frac{2\pi nx}{L}\right)dx \\&=\frac{2}{4\pi}\int_{-2\pi}^{2\pi}\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{2\pi nx}{4\pi}\right)dx\\&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-2\pi}^{2\pi}\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{nx}{2}\right)dx\\&=0\end{align}$$

and this has been verified [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%5Cpi%7D%5Ctimes%5Cint_%7Bx%3D-2%5Cpi%7D%5E%7B2%5Cpi%7D%5Ccos(x%2F2)%5Ctimes%5Ccos((nx)%2F2)dx) by Wolfram Alpha.

But according to this [answer](https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/fourier-series-f-x-cos-5-x-given-f-r-~-2-4-1-1-cos-nz-q32702042) given by "Chegg Study" website which gives the correct answer *but* the author does not extend the range of integration or change the argument of the cosine. So basically the author does not make the function periodic. Now it was my understanding that the Dirichlet conditions for convergence demand that a function must be periodic. Are the Dirichlet conditions wrong then?

---

Finally, my question is; why did the limits of integration need to be changed in the first example I gave, $f(x)=x^2$, but not for the second example of $f(x)=\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$?

I have researched this topic extensively in order to find an answer, here is a short extract from ["Mathematical Methods in the Physical Sciences", third edition by Mary L. Boas, Section 8, page 360](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/reader/0471198269/?tag=foxebook-21),
[image: Other Intervals, Boas]

The method used in the $x^2$ and $\cos(x/2)$ case was *general* and did **not** specify any restrictions on the function being extended.

So, put in another way, is there some kind of rule that says extending a *trigonometric function* to a full period is always forbidden since integrating over the period will be zero?

Comment: The root of your problem lies in this statement: "Since $\cos(x/2)$ is not periodic on $-\pi < x < \pi$..." That statement is non-sensical in this context. You can extend any function on $[-\pi,\pi)$ to a $2\pi$ periodic function on $\mathbb{R}$ by making copies of the graph on $[-\pi,\pi)$.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts Thanks, can you please elaborate on this by making an answer explaining why it is nonsensical for $\cos(x/2)$, but makes sense to extend $x^2$ from $0\lt x \le 2$ to $-2 \lt x \le 2$? It is understanding the distinction between these two cases that is causing me all the confusion here.

Comment: A function can be periodic on $\mathbb{R}$ with period $2\pi$. But that's different than saying it is periodic on $[-\pi,\pi]$, which doesn't make sense in this context.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts Thanks again, just one more question for you: [this](http://prntscr.com/li381x) was the statement that got me all cautious in the first place about the function needing to have a full period. According to what you are saying there was no need to be cautious at all. Was the author of the answer wrong to write this, since there was no need to extend the function to a full period? Or, put in another way; what was there to be cautious about?

Comment: I can see how that could lead to confusion. You are extending $\cos(x/2)$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$ to all of $\mathbb{R}$ so that it has period $2\pi$. He should be cautioning you not to confuse this periodic extension with the natural graph of $\cos(x/2)$, which has period $4\pi$.

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind is this: If a function $f$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}$ and is periodic with period $L$, then $\int_{a}^{a+L}f(x)dx$ has the same value, regardless of the value of $a$.