# Why does this method fail for finding the Fourier series for $\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$ on the interval $-\pi \lt x \lt \pi$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, trigonometric-integrals

This question is strongly related to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2993286/if-a-function-is-extended-to-make-it-periodic-then-must-the-integration-limits-a) (that does not have an answer).

From ["Riley, Hobson and Bence - Mathematical methods for physics and engineering", Section 12.5 - "Non-periodic functions", page 417](https://www.sicyon.com/resources/library/pdf/Math4phys.pdf)

$$a_n=\frac{2}{L}\int_{x_0}^{x_0+L}f(x)\cos\left(\frac{2\pi nx}{L}\right)dx\tag{1}$$

similarly $$b_n=\frac{2}{L}\int_{x_0}^{x_0+L}f(x)\sin\left(\frac{2\pi nx}{L}\right)dx\tag{2}$$ where $x_0$ is arbitrary but is often taken as $0$ or $-\frac{L}{2}$ and $L$ is the period of $f(x)$.

The following question I asked on "Chegg Study" website is [here](https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/fourier-series-f-x-cos-5-x-given-f-r-~-2-4-1-1-cos-nz-q32702042):

> Show that the Fourier series of $f(x)=\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$ for $-\pi\lt x \lt \pi$ is given by 
>   $$f(x)=\frac{2}{\pi}+\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}\cos(nx)}{4n^2 - 1}$$

---

So my attempt at the finding the Fourier series for $\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$ on the interval $-\pi \lt x \lt \pi$ is by first noting that since $\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$ is **not** periodic on $-\pi \lt x \lt \pi$,$\,$ I must therefore make the function periodic by extending the interval to $-2\pi \lt x \lt 2\pi$. By the Dirichlet conditions for convergence the function **must** be periodic.

Now that the function is symmetric and periodic about $x=0$ the $b_n=0 \,\forall \,n \in \mathbb N$

A plot of the extended function is shown below:

[image: cos(x/2)]

Now by $(1)$,
$$\begin{align}a_n &=\frac{2}{L}\int_{x_0}^{x_0+L}f(x)\cos\left(\frac{2\pi nx}{L}\right)dx \\&=\frac{2}{4\pi}\int_{-2\pi}^{2\pi}\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{2\pi nx}{4\pi}\right)dx\\&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-2\pi}^{2\pi}\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{nx}{2}\right)dx\\&=0\end{align}$$

and this has been verified [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%5Cpi%7D%5Ctimes%5Cint_%7Bx%3D-2%5Cpi%7D%5E%7B2%5Cpi%7D%5Ccos(x%2F2)%5Ctimes%5Ccos((nx)%2F2)dx) by Wolfram Alpha.

All I did was substitute the value of the period $L$ into the argument of the cosine, the limits and the denominator in front of the integral.

---

Why is this giving me the wrong answer when it clearly works for other functions like $x^2$ on $0 \lt x \le 2$ as can be seen here ["Riley, Hobson and Bence - Mathematical methods for physics and engineering", Section 12.5 - "Non-periodic functions", page 422 and 423](https://www.sicyon.com/resources/library/pdf/Math4phys.pdf)?

The method used in the $x^2$ and $\cos(x/2)$ case was *general* and did **not** specify any restrictions on the function being extended.

So, put in another way, is there some kind of rule that says extending a *trigonometric function* to a full period is always forbidden since integrating over the period will be zero?

Comment: seems to me you should not have changed the x range. - you are not looking to find a Fourier Series for cos(x/2) you are looking to fit a portion of the cos(x/2) curve - you should only care about what happens in the range $[-\pi,\pi]$ and forget the rest of the cos(x/2) function - does that make sense? -- You make the point that it is not periodic in this range, but that does not matter. the function is defined to repeat on the basis that $f(x+2\pi)=f(x)$ - it is discontinuous and looks wrong, but it is forced to repeat over $2\pi$

Comment: @tom I cannot "forget the rest of the cos(x/2) function" as by the Dirichlet conditions for convergence, the function being expanded must be periodic in order to have a Fourier series.

Comment: @tom Okay, have you seen [page 422 & 423 of this](https://www.sicyon.com/resources/library/pdf/Math4phys.pdf) where they expand $x^2$ on $[0,2]$ by extending the range to [−2,2] to make the function periodic? My question is simple; I would like to know why the method for $x^2$ does not work for $\cos(x/2)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to expand $\cos(x/2)$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$ in a Fourier series. The resulting series will converge to the periodic extension of $\cos(x/2)$ from $[-\pi,\pi]$ to $\mathbb{R}$ with period $2\pi$. The Fourier coefficients are
$$
    a_0 = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos(x/2)dx \\
    a_n = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos(x/2)\cos(n x)dx,\;\; n \ge 1 \\
    b_n = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos(x/2)\sin(n x)dx=0,\;\; n \ge 1.
$$
$b_n=0$ because the integrand is odd;
$a_n$ can be computed using the identity
$$
    \cos(x/2)\cos(n x)=\frac{1}{2}\{\cos(x/2+n x)+\cos(x/2-n x)\} \\
%%    \cos(x/2)\sin(n x)=\frac{1}{2}\{\sin(n x+x/2)+\sin(n x-x/2)\}.
$$
Using this,
$$
     a_n = \left.\frac{1}{2\pi}\left\{\frac{\sin(x/2+nx)}{1/2+n}+\frac{\sin(x/2-nx)}{1/2-n}\right\}\right|_{x=-\pi}^{\pi} \\
    = \frac{(-1)^n}{2\pi}\left[\frac{1}{n+1/2}-\frac{1}{n-1/2}\right] \\
    = \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{2\pi}\frac{1}{n^2-1/4}.
$$

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your answer. What I am questioning here is the *recipe* for finding the Fourier series and why it works for some functions (like the $x^2$ case) but not for other functions (the $\cos(x/2)$ case). Would you mind taking a look at my edit to the question to see if you can address this?

Comment: @BLAZE The function $\cos(x/2)$ being periodic on $-\pi < x < \pi$ is a statement that doesn't make sense. If you explain that statement, then you'll get at the root of the problem. When you perform a Fourier series, the resulting series will be a $2\pi$ periodic function. And your first coefficient formula works for arbitrary $x_0$ only if you have extended the function to a periodic function on $\mathbb{R}$ with period $L$.

Comment: @BLAZE : The standard Fourier series works on $2\pi$ periodic functions. However, your interval was $[-2\pi,2\pi]$, which has length $4\pi$. That's not the standard Fourier series.

Answer (score 2):

If you "extend the period" you get a rather different looking curve
[image]

The question that they are asking seem to be to evaluate.

$a_n = \frac 1{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \cos \frac x2 \cos nx\ dx\\
\frac {1}{4\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \cos (n+\frac 12)x + \cos (n-\frac 12)x \ dx\\
$

Comment: Yes, but by the Dirichlet conditions for convergence the function **must** be periodic. Your function is *not* periodic on $[-\pi, \pi]$

Comment: My answer follows yours, but I have gnuplot setup to produce something similar so it was easy to add the picture - like your answer it explains it better - I added mine just for the picture really - plus one :-)

Comment: @Doug Is there something special about $\cos(x/2)$ why I cannot extend the range of the function to make it periodic?

Comment: You have a function that is periodic with period $2\pi$  It is not the full period of $\cos \frac x2$ but instead $|\cos \frac x2|$

Comment: @Doug I think (finally) I am starting to understand you. My mistake was assuming that 'periodic' meant 'full period'. But these are not the same thing are they?

Comment: @DougM Hi there, could you please take a look at the edit I made to my question at the end and see if you can address this point? Thank you.

Comment: @BLAZE Regarding the text on pages 422, 3 of your text.  If you only care about the functions' behavior inside the interval, then sometimes it will simplify your calculations if you extend the interval.  If are trying to represent a periodic function, or a wave, then don't.

Answer (score 1):

$a_1=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-2\pi}^{2\pi}cos^2(\frac{x}{2})dx=\frac{1}{4\pi}\int_{-2\pi}^{2\pi}1dx=1$.

Comment: In my answer I used the fact that $cos^2(x)+sin^2(x)=1$ and the integrals over the range of $sin^2(x/2)$ and $cos^2(x/2)$ are equal.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This was generated with gnuplot - it shows a function that is defined by

$$f(x) = cos(x/2) \quad -\pi<x<\pi$$
and
$$f(x+2\pi)=f(x)$$

I think you need to stick to the range of $-\pi<x<\pi$ - which is what @DougM is saying in his answer

---

Edit about $x^2$ range extension...

The picture in the reference you gave is helpful here - where it shows the $x^2$ function being 'mirrored' or reflected in the $y$-axis.

So $x^2$ is an even function and so in the Fourier series we will only have contributions from $\cos(kx)$ and not $\sin(kx)$

This means that the critical integrals of 
$$\int x^2 \cos(kx) dx $$
are even - or at least the $x^2 \cos(kx)$ function inside is even.

Now if the function is even then integrating over the range $[0,2]$ will give exactly half the value that you get integrating over $[-2,2]$ - because everything is completely symmetrical about the $y$-axis or the line $x=0$.

In your case of the cos$(x/2)$ you also have an even function, but you are not expanding into the mirror image on the other side of the $y$-axis... instead you are making the range wider and the $\cos(x/2)$ function now is negative and things change.

For example - with the extended range the $a_0$ term will be zero, but in the figure above everything is above the $x$-axis so $a_0$ will be positive and non-zero.

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful stuff. Does it seem that the formulas given in the text book [on page 417](https://www.sicyon.com/resources/library/pdf/Math4phys.pdf) are wrong? Since all I did was apply them (as in the $x^2$ case) and got the wrong answer.

Comment: No the equations are fine... it is just a case of knowing when to apply which equation. - the pictures in Doug M's answer show that when you change the range for the cos(x/2) the whole shape of the function changes, whereas in the case of x^2 it is just a reflection in the axis and, of course, $x^2$ is symmetrical anyway about the yaxis... the reason the $x^2$ is extended is so that there is not a sudden drop or rise in the function - so that the two ends meet at the same height of +4...

Comment: Very impressive answer. Would you mind making an answer to [this previous (but longer version of this) question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2993286/if-a-function-is-extended-to-make-it-periodic-then-must-the-integration-limits-a) and see if you can summarize what you wrote here to make the distinction between the 2 cases where you can and *cannot* extend the range of the function?

Comment: I am afraid that I cannot do that at the moment, sorry - not enough time, but I think a key point about why the $x^2$ function was extended was so that at each end of the range $x^2$ = 4 so that when you make the function periodic and join it up the ends are at the same height - or y value - and touch

Comment: What I am questioning here is the *recipe* for finding the Fourier series and why it works for some functions (like the $x^2$ case) but not for other functions (the $\cos(x/2)$ case). Would you mind taking a look at my edit to the question to see if you can address this?

Comment: @BLAZE - sorry I have not been able to look at this, if I get time I will try to do something...